# Fluid layout with fixed left and fluid right

Tags: wordpress, css, flexbox, fluid-layout

On **[THIS](http://develop.rol.ro/mituri/)** page, I have blocks of code with `display: flex;`, each divided in 2: a div with a class of *myth-thumb*, with a fixed with and a div containing text that *should wrap*, so that the div has fluid width. But strangely he code does not wrap so the page is way too whide.

NOTE: the website uses WordPress as a CMS.

I relay cant understand the cause of this problem. What should I change to get the desired result? Thank you!

Comment: can you add your code markup and styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually with your content. When I look at the html in the dev tools inspector, it looks like this:

[image: HTML showing non-breaking spaces between workds]

Those `&nbsp` - 'non breaking space' - tags render as if they were normal spaces, but they don't allow the line to break. You need to convert those `&nbsp;`s to normal space characters. A text editor's find/replace tool can help you here, or you may be able to do it programmatically depending on your site's backend.

Comment: Is there a PHP way to do this cleanup?